# Einstein-Yang-Mills black holes in dS space

Tags: cosmology, gravity, black-holes

Can the Einstein-Yang-Mills black holes be calculated and investigated in the dS space? If this is possible, has there been any special work done so far, and if not, what is the reason why such a structure is not investigated in the dS space?